# Suddenly getting "These credentials do not match our records." in Laravel 5.2 - Ideas?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I have an app that was working fine until today. I could log in, log off, log back on. Things seemed to be working. Then I decided to test the reset password function. I am not the site developer. I am just doing some thorough testing after the fact. I know - I should have tested with the developers.

Anyway, here is what now happens:

1. Go to login page and click forgot password link
2. Enter email for account
3. Click reset link in email
4. Specify new password
5. Get automatically logged in with new password.
6. Logout
7. Click login and enter credentials
8. Get the annoying error "These credentials do not match our records."

The /config/auth.php file contains:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
| that is your password reset e-mail. You may also set the name of the
| table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
];
```

Maybe problem is related to whatever happens after the successful login. The AuthController is

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;
use Auth;
use Exception;
use Event;
use App\Events\UserVerifiedEvent;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
            'subscribe' => 'min:1',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $data['subscribe'] = ($data['subscribe'] == 1) ? 1 : 0;
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'subscribe' => $data['subscribe'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Overrides AuthenticatesUsers trait method.
     * Custom registration request handling for the application.
     */
    public function register(Request $request, Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        $user = $this->create($request->all());

        $mailer->send('auth/emails/verification', ['token' => $user->email_token], function ($message) use ($user) {
            $message->from('from', 'site')
                ->to($user->email)
                ->subject('Email Verification');
        });

        return view('auth/register')->withSuccess(true);
    }

    public function verifyEmail($token)
    {
        if ($token == null || $token == '') throw new Exception('Token must not be empty.');

        $user = \App\User::where('email_token', $token)->first();
        if ($user != null && !$user->verified)
        {
            $user->createProfile();
            $user->verifyEmail();

            Event::fire(new UserVerifiedEvent($user));

            //Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($user); // This could pose a security risk!
        }
        return redirect('/profile/welcome');
    }

    /**
     * Overrides AuthenticatesUsers trait method.
     * Custom credentials extraction method.
     */
    protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => $request['password'],
            'subscribe' => $request['subscribe'],
            'verified' => true
        ];
    }
}
```

The only thing worth mentioning here is I added the 'subscribe' field to the registration field, which is the only edit I made to above file. I can't see how that would affect things though, so I think the problem is related to login actions and maybe tokens or something not being reset.

When I run everything in debug mode with PHPStorm, I can see that the email and password are correctly being retrieved. Just can't figure out where in the process the core Auth routine is deciding that the login is invalid.

Also worth noting that when the error happens, the email field is marked in red. But that might just be default behavior regardless of which field is responsible for the error.

And here is the Password controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Hash;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

class PasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Create a new password controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', [
            'except' => ['showChangePasswordForm', 'changePassword']
        ]);
    }

    public function showChangePasswordForm()
    {
        return view('auth/passwords/change');
    }

    public function changePassword(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'old_password' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required',
        ]);

        $user = Auth::user();
        if (Hash::check($request['old_password'], $user->password))
        {
            $user->password = Hash::make($request['password']);
            $user->save();
            return view('auth/passwords/change')->withSuccess(true);
        }
        else
        {
            $errors = new MessageBag();
            $errors->add('old_password', 'Wrong password.');
            return redirect('/password/change')->withErrors($errors);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some middleware functions that might play a role here:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}

<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect()->intended('/'); // Uses Session
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And here is a listener which is involved in login in:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SuccessfulLoginListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Login  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        $user = $event->user;
        $user->last_login_at = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

        $user->save();
    }
}
```

These are all the code snippets in the app that I could find that seem to play a role in login in and out (the former more so than the latter!)

I have repeated this problem every time. I am entering same login credentials each time. So somehow login/logout processes are causing some weird state that I am having a hard time debugging. I also checked the database and don't see anything odd that would cause the retrieved data to not match against the credentials.

If someone sees something glaringly wrong in above, please let me know.

thanks!

PS - one other point worth mentioning - this problem happened around same time I created a second user for the app, which was done through the app's register page. I used same password as for the other user. And I had multiple browsers open, with multiple tabs, and several instances of logged in sessions. So maybe this is also key to the riddle?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out problem - in the AuthController I had added the 'subscribe' field to the getCredentials function. Definitely caused the problem! All is well now.